# rosdoc_lite and raw messages in generated documentaion

Tags: ros, rosdoc-lite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdoc_lite/issues/29

in the comments field

"Good point. I've put support for raw messages back in. This should fix up all the documentation the next time all the doc jobs run."

I have now tested the latest rosdoc_lite (latest Ubuntu packages) for private documentation and this does not work for me. And I cannot find any flag to rosdoc_lite to enable this. So how should I start rosdoc_lite to get the raw messages included in the generated documentation?

This all worked in rosdoc.

Adding more information_

Running by using target:

```
add_custom_target (lrs_msgs_doc 
  rosdoc_lite -o ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/doc/lrs_msgs ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/../src/lrs_msgs
)
```

The when running get the folloing output:

```
tompe@tpdell:~/lrs_ws$ catkin_make lrs_msgs_doc
Base path: /home/tompe/lrs_ws
Source space: /home/tompe/lrs_ws/src
Build space: /home/tompe/lrs_ws/build
Devel space: /home/tompe/lrs_ws/devel
Install space: /home/tompe/lrs_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/tompe/lrs_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make lrs_msgs_doc -j8 -l8" in "/home/tompe/lrs_ws/build"
####
Documenting a catkin package
Documenting lrs_msgs located here: /home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs
{'doxygen': {'builder': 'doxygen', 'output_dir': '.'}}
{'builder': 'doxygen', 'output_dir': '.'}
Generated the following tagfile string 
doxygen-ating lrs_msgs [doxygen /tmp/tmpsZf1og]
warning: tag INCLUDE_PATH: include path `$INCLUDE_PATH' does not exist
warning: source $INCLUDE_PATH is not a readable file or directory... skipping.
[('VisFrustrum', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/VisFrustrum.msg'), ('GeoPoint', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/GeoPoint.msg'), ('Sticks', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/Sticks.msg'), ('MPParams', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/MPParams.msg'), ('PtuExtData', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/PtuExtData.msg'), ('TFPOPProblem', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/TFPOPProblem.msg'), ('PMAVInfo', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/PMAVInfo.msg'), ('LQQueueInfo', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/LQQueueInfo.msg'), ('TFPOPAnswer', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/TFPOPAnswer.msg'), ('PlatformParams', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/PlatformParams.msg'), ('SticksValue', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/SticksValue.msg'), ('QuadState', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/QuadState.msg'), ('LQClimbCommand', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/LQClimbCommand.msg'), ('ThreeDObject', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/ThreeDObject.msg'), ('TSTNodeStatus', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/TSTNodeStatus.msg'), ('LQStatus', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/LQStatus.msg'), ('MPRefinements', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/MPRefinements.msg'), ('LQPtuCommand', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/LQPtuCommand.msg'), ('TFPOPPlan', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/TFPOPPlan.msg'), ('LQQueueCommands', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/LQQueueCommands.msg'), ('LQFlyCommand', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/LQFlyCommand.msg'), ('TFPOPRequest', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/TFPOPRequest.msg'), ('TFPOPThread', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/TFPOPThread.msg'), ('TSTInfo', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/TSTInfo.msg'), ('OMPLInfo', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/OMPLInfo.msg'), ('RMAXStatus', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/RMAXStatus.msg'), ('Point', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/Point.msg'), ('ExtData', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/ExtData.msg'), ('VisDelete', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/VisDelete.msg'), ('MPRoadmap', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/MPRoadmap.msg'), ('HeliState', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/HeliState.msg'), ('TSTNodeInfo', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/TSTNodeInfo.msg'), ('BinaryData', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/BinaryData.msg'), ('DelInfo', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/DelInfo.msg'), ('TSTSymbolicMap', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/TSTSymbolicMap.msg'), ('TFPOPAction', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/TFPOPAction.msg'), ('RefData', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/RefData.msg'), ('VisTrackBallHome', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/VisTrackBallHome.msg'), ('MotionPlan', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/MotionPlan.msg'), ('LQYawCommand', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/LQYawCommand.msg'), ('FIPAAclMessage', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/FIPAAclMessage.msg'), ('MPFlyingInfo', '/home/tompe/lrs_ws/src/lrs_msgs/msg/MPFlyingInfo.msg')]
[]
copying /opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdoc_lite/templates/msg-styles.css to /home/tompe/lrs_ws/devel/doc/lrs_msgs/html/msg-styles.css
Done documenting lrs_msgs you can find your documentation here: /home/tompe/lrs_ws/devel/doc/lrs_msgs
Built target lrs_msgs_doc
```

Happened to use hydro here but same result and failure in groovy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57078/rosdoc_lite-and-raw-messages-in-generated-documentaion/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-27**:
Looks like no one knows the answer to this question. Could you provide more information about exactly how you run it and what messages are displayed?

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-07-28**:
Did update the question with some more information.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-07-29**:
Have now read the source code and the change that includes the raw message text is not in the source code for rosdoc_lite. It should probably be in the template for the msg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For future reference, @TommyP discovered that the fix for [this issue (#29)](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdoc_lite/issues/29) had not been released.

A new rosdoc_lite release should be available soon.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0